# Union two queries ordered by newid

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that stores employees (id, name, and gender). I need to randomly get two men and two women.

```
CREATE TABLE employees 
(
    id INT, 
    name VARCHAR (10), 
    gender VARCHAR (1), 
);

INSERT INTO employees VALUES (1, 'Mary', 'F');
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (2, 'Jake', 'M');
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (3, 'Ryan', 'M');
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (4, 'Lola', 'F');
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (5, 'Dina', 'F');
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (6, 'Paul', 'M');
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (7, 'Tina', 'F');
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (8, 'John', 'M');
```

My attempt is the following:

```
  SELECT TOP 2 * 
  FROM employees
  WHERE gender = 'F'
  ORDER BY NEWID()

  UNION

  SELECT TOP 2 * 
  FROM employees
  WHERE gender = 'M'
  ORDER BY NEWID()
```

But it doesn't work since I can't put two `order by` in the same query.

Comment: Side note: for a string of a fixed length of **1** character - `VARCHAR(1)` is a bad choice - it will take 1-3 bytes of storage per entry. If the length is just one - use a `CHAR(1)` instead which will always be just 1 byte - for every single entry.

Comment: Also please default to `UNION ALL` in general, unless you explicitly want the behavior of `UNION` to remove duplicates from both sets (this is more expensive, because it can require additional sorts, especially when a lot of columns are involved, so whenever I see `UNION` in a PR, I always ask if they really need it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just use `row_number()`?  One method without a subquery is:

```
SELECT TOP (4) WITH TIES e.* 
FROM employees
WHERE gender IN ('M', 'F')
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY gender ORDER BY newid());
```

This is slightly less performant than using `ROW_NUMBER()` in a subquery.

Or, a fun method would use `APPLY`:

```
select e.*
from (values ('M'), ('F')) v(gender) cross apply
     (select top (2) e.*
      from employees e
      where e.gender = v.gender
      order by newid()
     ) e;
```

Comment: The second one is really interesting.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot put an `ORDER BY` in the *combinable* query (the first one) of the `UNION`. However, you can use `ORDER BY` if you convert each one into a table expression.

For example:

```
select *
from (
  SELECT TOP 2 * 
  FROM employees
  WHERE gender = 'F'
  ORDER BY newid()
) x
UNION ALL
select *
from (
  SELECT TOP 2 * 
  FROM employees
  WHERE gender = 'M'
  ORDER BY newid()
) y
```

Result:

```
 id  name  gender 
 --- ----- ------ 
 5   Dina  F      
 4   Lola  F      
 2   Jake  M      
 3   Ryan  M
```

See running example at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/94e85/2).